# process not killed even we used kill -9 and process actually was belong to container that already removed

Tags: rhel, process, docker, kill, container

here is a strange behavior that show how to kill a process , but actually process not killed

example ( from rhel 7.6 server )

```
ps -ef | grep kafka-exporter
root     15340 19528  0 17:25 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto kafka-exporter
root     28326     1 99 Oct18 ?        3-03:04:32 /bin/kafka-exporter --kafka.server=kafka1.sys76.com:6667
```

now we try to kill the process

```
kill -9 28326
```

and again see if process killed , but as we can see process still up

```
ps -ef | grep kafka-exporter
root     20204 19528  0 17:27 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto kafka-exporter
root     28326     1 99 Oct18 ?        3-03:07:54 /bin/kafka-exporter --kafka.server=kafka1.sys76.com:6667
```

as we know the process `kafka-exporter` is belong to docker container , but docker container already removed as we can see from the following

```
 docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

but from some unclear reason the binary - `/bin/kafka-exporter`  that should run in container also appears on the Linux OS

and actually when we did `ls -l /bin/kafka-exporter` , we can see that this binary file not exist

so any idea how to kill the process from the Linux OS , in spite this process was running under  docker container that already removed

Comment: If you have enough privileges to kill it (say, the process if _yours_), I have seeing this happening if the process is stopped (if I recall correctly). Is that the case?

Comment: I will say that , process was belong to container that already stop , but what I not understand is why process itself running on the OS while it was running in container , but any way we try to kill it but without success , only reboot actually solved this problem , but reboot isn't solution !

Comment: I C... _plus_ I think it's not the same I thought before. I think I have seen this with a simple `kill` on a process that was stopped, not `kill -9`.

Comment: very very strange , why the power full ( kill -9 ) cant kill the PID?

Comment: Did you check if it's a zombie process?

Comment: how to check that?

Comment: [How to find zombie process](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111422/how-to-find-zombie-process) - and find its parent which you must kill to kill the zombie, but often you do not want to kill the parent, because it is serving some important purpose.

Comment: its not displayed from ps aux | grep 'Z'

Comment: You can check with `ps -aux|grep -e '^USER' -e 'kafka-exporter'` how much %CPU %MEM it is using. If no significant usage, you can live with it. Otherwise maybe reboot (even if we don't like it).

Comment: yes memory and cpu are high , but we not want to do reboot , any other option to kill this pid?

Comment: Can you find its parent? (See the accepted answer in the same link as to find zombie.)

Comment: Did you try to `kill -9` with elevated permissions (as root or with sudo)?

Comment: yes kill -9 with root

Comment: "... that should run in container also appears on the Linux OS" - thats just how docker works, no? You can see all the processes from the containers via the "host machine".